# C++ Microsoft Foundation Classes installation error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mfc

Currently i am trying to add back to visual studio 2015 the microsoft foundation classes, but for some reason i keep getting errors on some missing files.(vc_mfc.source.msi, vc_mfc.headers.msi, vc_mfc.x64.msi, VC_IDE.Option.MFC.msi, vc_ide.mfc.res.msi and the list goes on) In the installer i get 3 options, try to download it, skip it, or provide the path to the package.

The download option does nothing, and i can't seem to find any of the missing file on my pc to provide the path.

Tried it on two different pc's and it is the same.Tried the "repair" option and the same. Also on a clean install, when selecting the mfc packages the same errors occurred.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd drop the old VS2015 and consider upgrading to VS2019

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option.

Comment: Is there an option to uninstall VS2015 completely and install it again with needed components ?

Comment: @flaviu2 It is the same..if i clean install, when i select the MFC pack at some point will get to the same error (missing or damaged files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix that i ended up with was to copy bunch of MFC files (should be called “atlmfc” ) from some other PC where MFC was previously installed (Back when it was still supported).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is one of the first google results for this VS2015 bug, here is a solution that worked for me.

Go to my.visualstudio.com or similar MS site and download Visual Studio Professional 2015 with Update 3.  The trial version is fine, you do not need a key.

The missing MFC installers are in "\packages\VisualC_D14" on the DVD image.  When prompted that a package is missing or damaged, browse to the respective subfolder in the VisualC_D14 and select the missing installer.

I didn't try using them, but the community edition VS2015 DVD also has the missing installers in "ServicedSetupPayloads\OfflineCache\installers\VSU_14.0.25420\en\0\packages\VisualC_D14", so you may be able to use those if you happen to have the Community edition installer handy and don't want to download Professional.